# Sequelize Global Hooks and Express - how to attach req.user to every hook

Tags: express, sequelize.js, hook, global

I want to attach the userId in every create or update I do with sequelize. Should work similar as the default timestamps.

Every model of my db has a field createdBy and updatedBy (that references a userId).

Instead of attaching the data of the user in every model.create() or model.update() I want to do create a global hook.

Something like:

```
sequelize.addHook('beforeCreate', populateCreatedBy);
```

But I dont find a "easy" way to attach the req.user that comes from my middleware to
the function populateCreatedBy().

I only found solutions that implies calling a hook on each model and passing the req.user to the model param and then retrieving it from the another hook after that. But I found it the same as just passing that propiety on each model.create()....

Is there any way to pass req.user to sequelize.addHook('beforeCreate',**populateCreatedBy()**)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In my example uses nestjs. All the same can be done on express.
Create the middleware, then define the following global hooks

```
//sequelize-attach-req-to-model.middleware.ts

import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { InjectConnection, } from "@nestjs/sequelize";
import { Sequelize, Model } from "sequelize-typescript";

interface ModelCustom extends Model {
  request: Request
}

@Injectable()
export class SequelizeAttachReqToModelMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private readonly sequelize: Sequelize) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('Request...');
    this.sequelize.beforeCreate((model: ModelCustom) => {
      model.request = req
    })
    this.sequelize.beforeUpdate((model: ModelCustom, options) => {
      model.request = req
    })
    this.sequelize.beforeDestroy((model: ModelCustom, options) => {
      model.request = req
    })
    next();
  }
}

//app.module.ts
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(SequelizeAttachReqToModelMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Next, usage the request in the model hooks

```
//services.model.ts

@Table({ tableName: 'services' })
export class CardService
  extends Model<InferAttributes<CardService>, InferCreationAttributes<CardService>>
  implements ICardsService {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 1, description: 'Уникальный индитефикатор' })
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true })
  id: CreationOptional<number>

  @ApiProperty({ example: 1, description: 'Название услуги' })
  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, unique: true })
  name: string

  @ApiProperty({ example: 1, description: 'Описание услуги' })
  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING })
  description: string

  @AfterCreate
  static afterCreateHook(instance, options: any) {
    return saveAuditLog('create', instance, options);
  }

  @AfterUpdate
  static afterUpdateHook(instance, options: any) {
    return saveAuditLog('update', instance, options);
  }

  @AfterDestroy
  static afterDestroyHook(instance, options: any) {
    return saveAuditLog('destroy', instance, options)
  }
}

async function saveAuditLog(action, model: ModelCustom, options) {
  const userFromRequest: User = model.request.user as User
  console.log(userFromRequest)

  const auditLog = await AuditLog.create({
    table_name: getOptions(model).tableName,
    table_row_id: model.get('id'),
    action: action,
    timestamp: new Date(),
    previous_values: model.previous(),
    current_values: model.get(),
    userId: userFromRequest.id
  });

  return auditLog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [spl33t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17993530/spl33t), I solved this by attaching a global hook to my sequelize in a middleware function that I then applied to my router:

middleware:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { sequelize } from '../models';

export default function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        sequelize.beforeUpdate('attachReqToModel', (model: any) => {
            model.request = req;
        });
        return next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

route:

```
import attachReqToModelMiddleware from '../middleware/attachReqToModel.middleware';
router.use(attachReqToModelMiddleware);
```

model:

```
@AfterUpdate
static exampleFunc(instance: any, options: any) {
    try {
        console.log(instance.request)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

To attach the actual user to the request, you should also use a middleware that runs before the above code, in my case I'm using JWT that stores the user id, and in my middleware I decode it and attach it to the request:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from '../config';

export default function(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

    const token = req.headers['authorization']?.split('Bearer ')[1];

    try {
        const jwtPayload = jwt.verify(token!, config.API_TOKEN_SECRET);
        if (!jwtPayload?.sub) {
            throw new Error('Missing or incorrect payload')
        }
        req.userId = Number(jwtPayload.sub);
        return next();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
}
```

and my routes file becomes:

```
import authnMiddleware from '../middleware/authn.middleware';
import attachReqToModelMiddleware from '../middleware/attachReqToModel.middleware';

router.use(authnMiddleware);
router.use(attachReqToModelMiddleware);
```

About the hook order, check [this link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/). You can use `afterValidate` as your global hook to attach the request to the model, and then you should have access to it in `beforeCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of doing this without calling the hook on each model. Instead you can try **session storage** for storing user data and updating that user data in model with `beforeUpdate()` or `beforeCreate()` hook.

Reference for global hooks - [Sequelize documentation for global hooks](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/#global--universal-hooks)

My recommendation for session storage is express sessions -
[express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Comment: Thanks, @Tyler2P for formatting the answer